# On a $\mathbb C$-linear map from $M(p-1,\mathbb C)$ to $\mathbb C^\hat G$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $G=\mathbb Z/(p) ^\times$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, characters, gauss-sums

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G=(\mathbb Z/(p))^\times=\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ i.e. $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Let $\hat G:=\{\chi:G \to \mathbb C^\times : \chi $ is a group homomorphism $\}$. For any set $X$, let $\mathbb C^X$ denote the set of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb C$, and note that this can be given a usual $\mathbb C$-algebra structure as $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x),\forall x\in X$ ; $(f.g)(x)=f(x)g(x), \forall x\in X$, and $(k.f)(x):=kf(x),\forall x\in X$.

Let $n=p-1$, let $\omega =e^{2\pi i/p}$ and define a function

$f:M(n,\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C^\hat G$ as $f(A)(\chi)=\begin{pmatrix} \chi(1) & ... & \chi(p-1) \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} \omega \\ \omega^2 \\ .\\.\\. \\ \omega^n \end{pmatrix} , \forall A \in M(n,\mathbb C), \forall \chi \in \hat G$.

It easily follows that $f$ is a $\mathbb C$-linear function.

Moreover, $f(A)=0 \implies A \begin{pmatrix} \omega \\ \omega^2 \\ .\\.\\. \\ \omega^n \end{pmatrix}=0$. From this, it follows that since the minimal polynomial of $\omega $ over $\mathbb Q$ has degree $p-1=n$, so $A \in M(n, \mathbb Q)$ and $A \begin{pmatrix} \omega \\ \omega^2 \\ .\\.\\. \\ \omega^n \end{pmatrix}=0 \implies A=O$, thus $A \in M(n, \mathbb Q)$ and $f(A)=0 \implies A=O$.

Now my questions are the following :

(1) For every $A,B \in M(n, \mathbb Q)$, does there exist $C \in M(n, \mathbb Q)$ such that $f(A).f(B)=f(C)$ ? (Notice that such a $C$, if exists, must be unique)

(2) How to show that there exists Hermitian matrices $A_1,...,A_n$ of rank $1$ such that $f(I)=f(A_1)+...+f(A_n)$ and $f(A_j)f(A_k)=0, \forall j \ne k$ ? (may be this has something to do with Orthogonality of characters ?)

Comment: So you meant $f(A)(\chi) =\chi(l) \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n A_{l,m} \omega^m$. Then $A \mapsto f(A)(.)$ is not injective as it depends only on $A\ (\omega_1,\ldots,\omega^n)^\top$

Comment: @reuns: $f(A)(\chi)=\sum_{l,m} \chi(l)A_{l,m} \omega^m$

Comment: Sure that was a typo. So what do you mean ? Letting the $p$-th root of unity vary it becomes injective as a function on pairs of multiplicative and additive character

Comment: @reuns: I mean to say that $f(A)(\chi)=0, \forall \chi \in \hat G \implies A=O$ ... at least that's what I believe and verified by brute force for $p=3$ ...

Comment: It implies $A\ (\omega_1,\ldots,\omega^n)^\top = 0$ not $A = 0$

Comment: @reuns: are you sure ? Because I am certain that it is true for $p=3$ ... I'm just staring at the calculation ... so there's something special about $p=3$ ?

Comment: ?? That $v^\top A w = 0$ for every $v$ implies $Aw = 0$ not $A = 0$. As I said, if you let your vector of $p$-th root of unity vary it won't be the same as those are a basis so it will become $v^\top A w = 0$ for every $v,w$ which implies $A = 0$.

Comment: @reuns: I have edited the question ...

Comment: $A \mapsto f(A)$ is surjective so you can always find a $C$. It is not unique since $A \mapsto f(A)$ is not injective.

Comment: @reuns: how is it surjective ?

Comment: Because $A \mapsto Aw$ is surjective and $u(n) = \sum_j c_j \chi_j(n) \implies \sum_n \chi(n) u(n) = (p-1) c_l$ where $\chi_l = \overline{\chi}$ (orthogonality of characters)

Comment: @reuns: sorry I didn't get that ... given a function $\phi : \hat G \to \mathbb C$, what is our $A$ ?

Comment: It is for example $b \ u \overline{\omega}^\top$ where $b = 1/\|\omega\|^2$ and $u (n) = \sum_j \phi(\chi_j) \overline{\chi_j(n)}$

Comment: thanks ... do you have any ideas for question (2) ? And in (1), do you think if we require $A,B \in M(n, \mathbb Q)$, then there is unique $C\in M(n, \mathbb Q)$ such that $f(A)f(B)=f(C)$ ?